# Override select.phtml for configurable product

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, product-view

I am trying to make some changes to the layout of the configurable product view.
This is my catalog.xml file

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml" translate="label">
                    <label>Info Column Options Wrapper</label>
                    <block type="core/template" name="options_js" template="catalog/product/view/options/js.phtml"/>
                    <block type="catalog/product_view_options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="catalog/product/view/options.phtml">
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>text</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_text</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>file</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_file</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>select</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_select</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>date</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_date</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/date.phtml</template></action>
                    </block>

                    <block type="core/html_calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="page/js/calendar.phtml"/>
                </block>
```

I would like to slightly change the way the options select is shown.

I duplicated the file

```
catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml
```

in my own theme design folder and tried to edit it but I can't see my changes on the frontend.
Am I modifying the right file. Or should I edit a different one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file I was modifying was not the right one. The file to edit is this

```
catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml
```